# Unable to create a sqllite test database in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, pytest

I am building a laboratory management software right now as a passion project, and I am getting stuck trying to test the Django backend of my application. I am trying to create a test database to use with pytest. I am using MySQL on PlanetScale as the default database, but if I were to create a second database for testing, I would have to upgrade from the free version. If possible, I want to avoid this, so I'm trying to use a SQLite database for testing. I need to figure out how to run my pytests using a second sqlite database.

To begin, I run pytest using my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk del build-deps
COPY . /code/
RUN pytest -v
```

Once it starts running the pytests I receive an error, and all errors I receive from any test are the same. An example test would be

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_user_serializer_save(valid_user_data):
    serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=valid_user_data)
    assert serializer.is_valid() == True
    user = serializer.save()
    assert User.objects.filter(email=valid_user_data['email']).exists() == True
    assert user.name == valid_user_data['name']
```

The error I receive for all the tests are...

```
#0 10.97 self = <django.db.backends.mysql.creation.DatabaseCreation object at 0x7f77b3918b50>
#0 10.97 cursor = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f77b2b36b10>
#0 10.97 parameters = {'dbname': '`test_lms-msd`', 'suffix': ''}, keepdb = False
#0 10.97 
#0 10.97     def _execute_create_test_db(self, cursor, parameters, keepdb=False):
#0 10.97         try:
#0 10.97             super()._execute_create_test_db(cursor, parameters, keepdb)
#0 10.97         except Exception as e:
#0 10.97             if len(e.args) < 1 or e.args[0] != 1007:
#0 10.97                 # All errors except "database exists" (1007) cancel tests.
#0 10.97                 self.log("Got an error creating the test database: %s" % e)
#0 10.97 >               sys.exit(2)
#0 10.97 E               SystemExit: 2
#0 10.97 
#0 10.97 /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py:27: SystemExit
#0 10.97 ---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
#0 10.97 Creating test database for alias 'default'...
#0 10.97 Got an error creating the test database: (1105, 'create database is not supported')
```

I'm under the impression that this means it is still trying to access my MySQL database. I want to use the SQLite database to test the basics of the program instead. My settings.py with the specified databases and my pytest.ini file.

```
# PlanetScale config
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_psdb_engine',    
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'ssl': {'ca': os.getenv('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')},
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    },
    "test": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = api.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts = --nomigrations --cov=. --cov-report=html
```

The requirements.txt

```
# Standard dependencies
asgiref
backports.zoneinfo;python_version<"3.9"
django
python-dotenv
djangorestframework
django-cors-headers

# PlanetScale dependencies
pymysql
django-mysql
mysqlclient
sqlparse
pytz

# auth dependencies
Authlib

# testing dependencies
pytest
pytest-django
pytest-cov
```

Can anyone help me figure out to set up testing my application? I'm not dead set on this method if there are any other suggestions on how to go about this.

Comment: That‘s not a correct way to define settings for a test database. Right now, you simply defined a second database named `test` which is ignored since your app uses the default one. You need to define custom settings module for testing and redefine the backend for the default database in there.

Comment: Like to create another settings file, I've been able to create a settings_test.py that seems to work so far. It just seems redundant, is there any way around this?

Comment: Sure, I assume you use `pytest-django` plugin? You can e.g. override the database settings in a custom `django_db_modify_db_settings` fixture, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799349/2650249) with an example.

Comment: However, should you need to override other settings, this fixture (and other fixtures) might be too late for this, so you will need to resort to a `pytest_configure` hookimpl and start merging custom config into application settings, which usually gets pretty hairy. I find it more Django-conform to simply define a custom settings module that has a `from app_settings import *` and redefines the necessary minimum, easier to find and understand the settings modifications later.